# Background animation stutters when I press a button

Tags: java, android, android-studio, animation, animationdrawable

I am building a mobile app on android studio using Java. I am using animation drawable to create a background animation on an image view. I have a button on the same activity that when pressed makes a window pop up. Once the button is pressed the background animation starts to lag. I am wondering is there a way I can keep the background animation separate to the button so that it does not lag?

This is my main activity class:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {


AnimationDrawable backgroundAnimation;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ImageView backgroundView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.backgroundView);
    backgroundView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.animation_bg);
    backgroundAnimation = (AnimationDrawable) backgroundView.getBackground();


    final Button popUpButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    popUpButton.setOnClickListener((view) -> {

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View popupView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_pop_up, null);
        PopupWindow pw = new PopupWindow(popupView, WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        pw.showAtLocation(view, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);


    });

}


//do something after on create
@Override
protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);

    backgroundAnimation.start();
}
```

}

Comment: lag = too much to process. lower the resolution of the image..

Comment: There are five images for the animation and they are Vectors. I also think the lag is because the button is interrupting the animation frames. That is why I was thinking maybe the animation can be separated from the button etc. I am not sure though.